# SQL SELECT * returns only one row

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm designing a website and I wrote some webpage that display the list of users. 
I used to do a

```
$query = SELECT * FROM `table_users` WHERE `id`='.$id.'
```

and then increment the ID with a "while" so I can grab all the users. But it's too slow now, and it glitches when there is a gap between IDs.

So I tried something like

```
$query = SELECT `name` FROM `tbl_user`ORDER BY `id`
```

and displaying the userlist with a

```
while ($i < sizeof(mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query)))){
<code to display an user>
$i++
}
```

But the mysql_fetch_array only returnes one user, the first one (the one with the littliest ID). I want it to return all users in an array. How do I do ?

Comment: don't use mysql_* use either mysqlI og pdo

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_'` API. Use `mysqli_` or `PDO` with prepared statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
$query = "SELECT `name` FROM `tbl_user` ORDER BY `id`";
$user_query = mysql_query($query);

$i=1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($user_query)){
  echo $i." : ".$row['name']."<br>";
  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     //$row is the row which was just gathered
}
```

And please, use PDO or MySQLi instead of deprecated mysql.

Comment: I know all of you want me to use mysqli or PDO but since my whole website is using MySQL and I know nothing about both, i'm not converting my website for now.

I'm going to try what you said.

Comment: Not working. The while get stuck in an infinite loop and returns nothing. Could you develop ?

Comment: note that what the above will return - and it will work, will be an array from which you can either extract($row); and call the column values from each row using the column name as the variable name. or you can refer to them by using the $row['column_name'] array value.

Comment: The while can't get stuck in an infinite loop. The while gets terminated as soon as there are no more rows. You're probably doing something wrong. Please paste more code here so we can check. Also add how many rows does your table have, it could be that there are too many rows (under too many, I mean atleast 100k).

Comment: First assign mysql_query($query) to a variable, otherwise it will execute the query again and again and it will indeed get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Right, thanks for that Bert, edited my answer by that.